# Drag selected text with the mouse

Tags: text-editing, mouse, drag-and-drop

In many editors it is standard to move selected text by dragging and dropping it with the mouse.

In emacs dragging selection with the mouse starts a new selection by default.

This is extremely annoying, as normally (everywhere else) such a behavior is achieved by clicking mouse to deselect text first. Besides, I cannot imagine a single use case for this emacs behavior - starting a new selection immediately after the first one without doing anything with the first selection.

How can I configure emacs to drag existing selection like in all other editors?

Comment: Hmmm . . . I was a professional word processor / typist from about 1986 to 2002, and I've worked for myself doing my own document preparation from 2002 to the present.  I can honestly say that this is the first time I've ever even thought about the possibility of dragging text with the mouse.  :)  I'll definitely have to give that a try.  :)

Comment: Sure, emacs is all about keyboard, but why then enable mouse there and not have it implemented in a way it is expected to be?

Comment: @AlexanderShcheblikin Maybe give the implementers the benefit of doubt? What you expect seems to be different from what they expect, but maybe there is a reason? (I've never dragged and dropped text in any program, Emacs or other, for what it is worth, so I have no idea what to expect).

Comment: Check out the inbuilt `mouse-copy` package. I'll write a proper answer when I get to a computer. You can search for `mouse-copy` in my [config](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/master/setup-files/setup-editing.el).

Comment: FYI to easily drag stuff with the keyboard: https://github.com/rejeep/drag-stuff.el

Answer (score 12):

**tldr**;

- Add `(setq mouse-drag-and-drop-region t)` in you init file.
- Restart or <kbd>C-c d R</kbd> to reload if you're using Doom-Emacs.

[image]

I just find out (SURPRISINGLY) that Emacs as text drag and drop. And this since version 22.1 released in 2007.
This is actually a feature I didn't even dare to google to see if it's available.
Even Sublime Text can't (currently in Linux)

Comment: support for DnD It appears to be limited to the current frame.  I can drag text from one area of my buffer and drop it in another area, and I can split my frame and open a second buffer and drag text between the two, but I can't drag text from one frame and drop it into another frame (or into another application).  Ubuntu 18.10 with GNOME 3 and `emacs --daemon`, in case any of that matters.

Comment: Yes, I just find that limitation. At least you can drop text from other application, not the other way around.

Comment: Can you scroll with the mouse wheel while dragging?

Comment: @AlexanderShcheblikin I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Added this variable and it has no effect for me (after restart). Just changes the selection and sets the mark, as before.

Comment: Also the `C-h v mouse-drag-and-drop-region` says ''Not documented as a variable. This is in emacs 25.1.1 in Debian 9

Comment: @AlexanderShcheblikin I just test holding the mouse while dragging but it doesn't work here.